# Print PDF to XPS using Powershell

Tags: powershell, pdf, xps

I would like to convert a folder containing PDF files into XPS files using Powershell. Due to system restrictions, I am unable to download any third party software like iTextSharp to make this work.

I have been able to get Powershell to open the document and open the print window for XPS, but the name is always blank. Is it possible to have the new file name match the original file name?

Also, how can the process be automated so user input is not required (ie entering the file name or pressing print)? Lastly, is it possible to change the directory that it prints to?

```
Get-ChildItem -path $pdf_filepath -recurse -include *.pdf | ForEach-Object {Start-Process -FilePath $_.fullname -Verb Print -PassThru | %{sleep 10;$_} }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
#Define the directory containing your .pdf files
$mydir="$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\New folder"
function print_files($mydir){
    #The purpose of this counter is to number your .xps files
    Get-ChildItem $mydir -Filter *.pdf -Recurse | Foreach-Object {
        #For each .pdf file in that directory, continue
        same_time $_.FullName
    }
}
#The following function keeps checking for a new window called "Save Print Output As". When the window shows up, it enters the name of the file and press ENTER.
function enter_my_names($fullname){
    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
    while($wshell.AppActivate('Save Print Output As') -ne $true){
        $wshell.AppActivate('Save Print Output As')
    }
    $basename = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($fullname)
    #This is where the name is actually entered
    $wshell.SendKeys("$basename")
    $wshell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
}
#The following function launches simultaneously a print job on the input file and a function waiting for the print job to show up to name the file.
workflow same_time{
    Param(
        $fullname
    )
    parallel{
        Start-Process -FilePath $fullname –Verb Print -PassThru
        enter_my_names($fullname)
    }
}
#MAIN PROGRAM
#Here the script saves your current printer as default
$defprinter = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_Printer Where Default=$true"
#Queries for a XPS printer
$printer = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_Printer Where Name='Microsoft XPS Document Writer'"
#Sets the XPS printer as Default
$printer.SetDefaultPrinter()
#Starts the main job
print_files($mydir)
#Sets the old default printer back as default again
$defprinter.SetDefaultPrinter()
#This is a small delay to be sure everything is completed before closing Adobe Reader. You can probably shorten it a bit
sleep 5
#Finally, close Adobe Reader
Get-Process "acrord32" | Stop-Process
```

Cheers!

Comment: The print_files function gets the names of the files in the directory and stores those names in the C:\c folder for later use.
The enter_my_names function opens the window, recalls the name stored in C:\c and prints the file with a new name.
The workflow calls the enter_my_names function to run in parallel to make it faster.
And finally, the print_files actually prints the files to the designated directory then removes the unncessary info from C:\c.
Did I describe that accurately?  I am running into issues where the subsequent files attempt to overwrite because the name isn't changing.

Comment: @MrKGado I modified the script. Now it's definitely better. It's also commented so that you can better understand each section. It requires to have Adobe Reader installed, hope it's not a major problem. Have a nice day

Comment: That is very helpful, thank you! How can I use the Get-ChildItem to collect the original file names so the printed files have the same name? I tried modifying lines 6 & 8 along with the other $counter pieces but just ended up breaking it each time. I used 
`Get-ChildItem -Path $mydir -Recurse -Name` to gather the file names, but I haven't been able to find how to link them to the print save name.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @MrkGado The part you needed to modify was the function enter_my_names. I modified it accordingly.

Comment: Last two questions.  I modified this to then convert those xps files back to PDFs (necessary to remove security preventing adding comments) and it works great.  However, it requires user input when the "Print" screen appears.  Also, it doesn't save in the same directory.  How do I automate the "Print" screen (SendKeys?), and how do I change the directory to save it in (either the same folder as the xps files or choose, doesn't matter)?  Thank you again!

Comment: I was able to solve the first question by adding the following function then calling it in sequence in the workflow.  `function press_enter($enter){
    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
    while($wshell.AppActivate('Print') -ne $true){
        $wshell.AppActivate('Print')
    }
    $wshell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
}` 
Still at a loss for changing the print directory.