# Print PDF to XPS back to PDF via Powershell

Tags: powershell, pdf, xps

After getting help in [Print PDF to XPS using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44435385/print-pdf-to-xps-using-powershell) I made two scripts: one converts a PDF to XPS and the other XPS to PDF using a workflow.  When combining them into one script, the first workflow converts the file to XPS, however, the second workflow doesn't seem to work at the appropriate time or at all.

There are some cleanup items at the end of the second workflow that do seem to be working properly.  Can I delay the start of the second workflow somehow to start at the appropriate time?

```
# Define the directories used for converting files 
$secure_pdf_dir = Select-FolderDialog # the variable contains user folder selection
$xps_dir = "aaa"
$unsecure_pdf_dir = "bbb"
$secure_pdf_archive = "ccc"
$xps_archive = "ddd"
$unsecure_pdf_archive = "eee"

$date = $(get-date -f yyyy-MMM-dd)


# Archives old files except secure pdfs
# Archives old xps files
New-Item $xps_archive\$date -type Directory
copy-Item $xps_dir\* -Recurse $xps_archive\$date -force
Remove-Item $xps_dir\*

# Archives old unsecure pdf files
New-Item $unsecure_pdf_archive\$date -type Directory
copy-Item $unsecure_pdf_dir\* -Recurse $unsecure_pdf_archive\$date -force
Remove-Item $unsecure_pdf_dir\*


# Converts PDF to XPS
function print_files($secure_pdf_dir){
    #The purpose of this counter is to number your .xps files
    Get-ChildItem $secure_pdf_dir -Filter *.pdf -Recurse | Foreach-Object {
        #For each .pdf file in that directory, continue
        same_time $_.FullName
    }
}

# The following function keeps checking for a new window called "Save Print Output As". When the window shows up, it enters the name of the file and press ENTER.
function enter_my_names($fullname){
    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
    while($wshell.AppActivate('Save Print Output As') -ne $true){
        $wshell.AppActivate('Save Print Output As')
    }
    $basename = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($fullname)
    #This is where the name is actually entered
    $wshell.SendKeys("$basename")
    $wshell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
}


# The following function launches simultaneously a print job on the input file and a function waiting for the print job to show up to name the file.
workflow same_time{
    Param(
        $fullname
    )
    parallel{
        Start-Process -FilePath $fullname –Verb Print -PassThru
        enter_my_names($fullname)
    }
}

# MAIN PROGRAM
# Here the script saves your current printer as default
$defprinter = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_Printer Where Default=$true"
# Queries for a XPS printer
$printer = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_Printer Where Name='Microsoft XPS Document Writer'"
#Sets the XPS printer as Default
$printer.SetDefaultPrinter()
# Starts the main job
print_files($secure_pdf_dir)
# Sets the old default printer back as default again
$defprinter.SetDefaultPrinter()
# This is a small delay to be sure everything is completed before closing Adobe Reader. You can probably shorten it a bit
sleep 5
# Finally, close Adobe Reader
Get-Process "acrord32" | Stop-Process

Move-Item $secure_pdf_dir\*.oxps $xps_dir

# Converts XPS to PDF
function print_xps_files($xps_dir){
    #The purpose of this counter is to number your .xps files
    Get-ChildItem $xps_dir -Filter *.oxps -Recurse | Foreach-Object {
        #For each .pdf file in that directory, continue
        same_time $_.FullName
    }
}


# The following function keeps checking for a new window called "Save Print Output As". When the window shows up, it enters the name of the file and press ENTER.
function enter_my_xps_names($fullname){
    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
    while($wshell.AppActivate('Save Print Output As') -ne $true){
        $wshell.AppActivate('Save Print Output As')
    }
    $basename = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($fullname)
    #This is where the name is actually entered
    $wshell.SendKeys("$basename")
    $wshell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
}


function press_enter($enter){
    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
    while($wshell.AppActivate('Print') -ne $true){
        $wshell.AppActivate('Print')
    }
    $wshell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
}


# The following function launches simultaneously a print job on the input file and a function waiting for the print job to show up to name the file.
workflow same_time2{
    Param(
        $fullname
    )
    sequence{
        Start-Process -FilePath $fullname –Verb Print -PassThru
        press_enter($enter)
        enter_my_xps_names($fullname)
    }
}


# MAIN PROGRAM
# Here the script saves your current printer as default
$defprinter = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_Printer Where Default=$true"
# Queries for a XPS printer
$printer = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_Printer Where Name='Microsoft XPS Document Writer'"
# Sets the XPS printer as Default
$printer.SetDefaultPrinter()
# Starts the main job
print_files($xps_dir)
# Sets the old default printer back as default again
$defprinter.SetDefaultPrinter()
# This is a small delay to be sure everything is completed before closing Adobe Reader. You can probably shorten it a bit
sleep 5

# Archives old secure pdfs
# Archives old secure pdf files
New-Item $secure_pdf_archive\$date -type Directory
copy-Item $secure_pdf_dir\* -Recurse $secure_pdf_archive\$date -force
Remove-Item $secure_pdf_dir\*
```

Comment: Why not add a reference to the other questions? Your code already spends time waiting. Just use the instruction to wait some more at the appropriate time. In addition as you already know you want to do both just combine them into one workflow?

Comment: I think the problem with combining them into one workflow is that they both look for a window with the same title "Save Print Output As".  I have tried using wait-process between the two main scripts with no luck getting it to work properly.  I tried inputting it after the `Get-Process "acrord32" | Stop-Process` hoping it would allow one workflow to stop and the other to start.  How would I make it wait longer?